# javascript. pick element from random array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am trying make 'color guessing' script.

```
<body onload="do_game()">
        <script>
            var color=[blue,gold, grey,hotpink, maroon,olive,pink, purple, red,tan,];
            var random_color;
            var finished = false;
            var guess_input_text;
            var guess_input;
            var random_color = Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length);
            var guess;
            var target;

            do_game(){
                while(!finished){
                    guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors\n\n"
                                                +color[]\n\n+"What color am I thinking of?\n");
                        target = color.indexOf(random_color);
                        guess_input = parseInt(guess_input_text);

                }
            }


        </script>
    </body>
```

It keeps giving me parsing error. 
The reason I put parseInt is that I want user type color.
Is there other way I can make user type color they are guessing until they correct(which should be same as *target*)?

Thank you,

Comment: You have to quote those colors

Comment: ` prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors\n\n"
                                                +color[]\n\n+"What color am I thinking of?\n");` this line seems to incorrect because \n should be inside double qoutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few syntax errors in your code.

```
var color = ['blue', 'gold', 'grey', 'hotpink', 'maroon', 'olive', 'pink', 'purple', 'red', 'tan'];
var random_color;
var finished = false;
var guess_input_text;
var guess_input;
var random_color = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
var guess;
var target;

function do_game() {
    while (!finished) {
        guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors\n\n" + color + "\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?\n");
        target = color.indexOf(random_color);
        guess_input = parseInt(guess_input_text);
    }
}
```

Some things I fixed:

- Colors should be in quotes because they are strings
- To print the array, just use the variable name `color`, not `color[]` (use `color[x]` only when you need to access a specific item at index `x` where `x` is an integer
- The `\n\n` needs to be in quotes as part of a string
- Missing the `function` keyword when declaring `do_game()`

Hopefully this gets you a bit closer to your goal. There are some additional issues not related to syntax:

- `finished` never becomes `true`, so your code is going to run forever (in other words, infinite prompts)
- I don't think [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) is doing what you want it to do, since `random_color` is an index, not a color
- `parseInt` is unnecessary here, since you are comparing strings

To elaborate on that last point: you want the user to type a color, which will be a string. Only use `parseInt` if you want to convert what they type into a number. You already have the user's guess stored in `guess_input_text`, so you just have to compare it to `target` using `===`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am gonna try it again!!